# req.url not showing the full URL

Tags: node.js, express, restify

I'm using Restify and for some reason req.url is only showing the URL up to the first query parameter.  req.query is also only showing queryStartDate.

```
http://localhost:6001/myapp/v1/filter/path1/path2/v4.0/mhs/query/path3/path4/path5?queryStartDate=19000101&queryEndDate=21000101&requestSource=source&includeSources=1&excludeSources=2
```

Code:

```
//Breakpoint in my first handler:
HttpHandlers.prototype.readHttpRequest = function (req, res, next) {
        req.locals = {};
        res.locals = {}; 
...

var httpHandlers = new HttpHandlers();
server.get('/hello/:name', httpHandlers.readHttpRequest );
```

Comment: How do you this. Code behind?

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper, I just updated my question.

Comment: Where is your **/hello/:name** url? @user994165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by my sending the URL with curl and not surrounding the URL with double quotes.  Linux see the "&" and runs the preceding command in the background, so Node.js only see everything before the first "&".

Comment: can you please explain more how did u sent the url, i added double quote still not able to access full url including query param